# PHP Check Function Parameters and Set Nulls If Empty

Tags: php, mysql, function, prepared-statement

I have a PHP function that accepts a number (lot) of parameters via a web form.

Is it possible to check if **any** of these parameters are **empty**, and if so, set these parameters to `null` values? I understand there's probably a much more effective way of achieving what I am doing, but how can I proceed with my current code?

Rather than checking each one individually like my sample code below, is there a more efficient way?

```
public function test ($param1, $param2, $param3, $param4, $param5, $param6, $param7, ... ) {
        $param1 = ($param1 != '') ? $param1 : NULL;
        $param2 = ($param2 != '') ? $param2 : NULL;
        $param3 = ($param3 != '') ? $param3 : NULL;
        $param4 = ($param4 != '') ? $param4 : NULL;
        $param5 = ($param5 != '') ? $param5 : NULL;
        $param6 = ($param6 != '') ? $param6 : NULL;
        $param7 = ($param7 != '') ? $param7 : NULL;
        // etc
    }
```

I am then using prepared statements in order to send these values to a mysql db.

Comment: I assume these `params` come from a form or other user input?

Comment: I'd rather go with parameters as array and `array_walk` function

Comment: i would more into the direction off writting a custom form [validator](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation) like Laraval supports.. And see if the form data is valid or not...if the form is valid meaning all required data inputs are there do the insert.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use an associative array instead of individual variables. The associative array maps a string key to a value.

I will eventually pass this associative array to the `PDOStatement::execute()` method, as parameters for a prepared statement. This means all the keys must be present, and *only* the keys named in the prepared statement.

So I need my param array to be both filled out with defaults if they're not in the array, and I need it to be truncated to remove elements not needed.

```
public function fillAndTruncate($params, $paramDefaults) {
  $params = array_merge($paramDefaults, array_intersect_key($params, $paramDefaults));
  return $params;
}
```

I might use this function like this:

```
$paramDefaults = [
  'name'    => NULL,
  'phone'   => NULL,
  'age'     => 0,
  'country' => 'USA'
];

$sql = 'INSERT INTO mytable SET name = :name, phone = :phone, age = :age, country = :country';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(fillAndTruncate($_POST, $paramDefaults));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you load the params in a single variable, you can do a simple foreach and there is no need to have an else as you do in the question because you are only changing the value if it is empty.

**Your form and it's inputs would look something like this:**

```
<form action="action-calling-your-function.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="params[]" />
    <input type="text" name="params[]" />
</form>
```

**The function could then look like this:**

```
public function test ($params) {
    foreach ($params as $param) {
        if (empty($param))
            $param = NULL;
    }
}
```

Note: I also used the `empty()` function which includes the desired value of `''` but other values would return true.  [Here is the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)